# boost::icl::contains unable to check for subset

Tags: boost-icl

```
  boost::icl::interval_map<int, boost::icl::interval_map<int, boost::icl::interval_set<int>>> larger, smaller; 

  larger.add(make_pair(boost::icl::discrete_interval<int>::closed(102,104), 
      boost::icl::interval_map<int, boost::icl::interval_set<int>>{ 
          make_pair(boost::icl::discrete_interval<int>::closed(0,0), boost::icl::interval_set<int {boost::icl::discrete_interval<int>::closed(2,4)})})); 

  smaller.add(make_pair(boost::icl::discrete_interval<int>::closed(103,103), 
      boost::icl::interval_map<int, boost::icl::interval_set<int>>{ 
          make_pair(boost::icl::discrete_interval<int>::closed(0,0), boost::icl::interval_set<int>{boost::icl::discrete_interval<int>::closed(3,3)})})); 

  cout << larger << endl; 
  cout << smaller << endl; 
  cout << boost::icl::contains(larger, smaller) << endl; 
  cout << ((smaller & larger) == smaller) << endl;
```

As given above, I'm trying to check if smaller is subset of larger. But I 
get following output:

```
{([102,104]->{([0,0]->{[2,4]})})} 
{([103,103]->{([0,0]->{[3,3]})})} 
0 
1
```

Any reason why `boost::icl::contains(larger, smaller)` doesn't work but 
`((smaller & larger) == smaller)` works?

Comment: What version of boost are you using? What version of C++ are you using? You should post a MWE that compiles so users can help you easily.